# recebo código 404 num PUT mas em GET funciona normalmente: {body: {…}, url: "api/modes/1", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}

Tags: angular, http-request

Sou estudante e iniciante em Angular e no momento vou seguir para utilização de TDF em um projeto, mas antes disso estou preparando methods de CRUD para então poder trabalhar em cima deles, até então estou passando por problemas de request e não entendo o que estou fazendo de errado, quando faço um GET utilizando a Url `api/modes` ou `api/modes/1` a requisição e bem sucedida, mas ao tentar fazer um PUT utilizando do endereço `api/modes/1` e me retornado um erro `404`:

> {body: {…}, url: "api/modes/1", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}

Estou utilizando:

- Angular 9.1.8
- Angular in-memory-web-api 0.11.0

**#mode.service.ts**

```
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Mode } from "./mode.model";

@Injectable()

export class ModeService {
  public modeUrl = "api/modes";

  public constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getModes(): Observable<Mode[]> {

    return this.http.get<Mode[]>(this.modeUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleErrors)
      )

  }
  
  public getMode(id: number): Observable<Mode> {
    let url = `${this.modeUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http.get<Mode>(url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleErrors)
      )
  }

  public updateMode(mode: Mode): Observable<Mode> {
    let url = `${this.modeUrl}/${mode.id}`;
    let body = JSON.stringify(mode);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
    
    return this.http.put<Mode>(url, body, {headers: headers} )
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleErrors)
      )

  }

  private handleErrors(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log("SALVANDO O ERRO NUM ARQUIVO DE LOG - DETALHES DO ERRO => ", error);
    return throwError(error);
  }

}
```

**#mode-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

// import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Mode } from '../shared/mode.model';
import { ModeService } from '../shared/mode.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'mode-detail',
  templateUrl: './mode-detail.component.html'
})

export class ModeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public mode: Mode;

  public constructor (
    private modeService: ModeService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(switchMap(
        (params: Params) => this.modeService.getMode(+params['id'])))
      .subscribe(
        mode => this.mode = mode,
        error => alert("Ocorreu um erro no servidor, tente mais tarde.")
      );
  }

  public updateMode() {
    if (!this.mode.name) {
      alert("O módulo deve ter um nome")
    } else {
      this.modeService.updateMode(this.mode)
        .subscribe(
          () => alert("Módulo atualizado com sucesso!"),
          () => alert("Ocorreu um erro no servidor, tente mais tarde.")
        )
    }
  }  

  public goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

**#mode-detail.component.html**

```
<h1 class="page-header font-weight-black text-secondary">Módulo {{ mode?.name }}</h1>
<br>
<div class="container-fluid bg-light shadow rounded ">

  <br>
  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="mode">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label text-body">Nome</label>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input [(ngModel)]="mode.name" type="text" class="form-control text-muted" placeholder="Nome">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default text-secondary" (click)="goBack()">Voltar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium text-light" (click)="updateMode()">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br>

</div>
```

[image: Error Console]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atualizando:

Fiz a desinstalação do pacote [angular in memory api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api), essa lib servia pra interceptar as requisições HTTP e simular respostas, mas infelizmente usando-a nesse projeto em `Angular 9` não funcionou de nenhuma forma das quais tentei, diferente de outro projeto em que desenvolvo em `Angular 4` ao qual funciona perfeitamente nele.

Após desinstalar o pacote acima, fiz a troca pelo pacote [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server), ela fará o mesmo trabalho em responder as requisições HTTP, achei um pouco mais simples que a outra mas para o meu caso de utilizar em CRUD veio a funcionar muito bem!